# ionic v2 error ionic view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I'm developing an ionic v2 app but even working on ionic lab it gets a complete white screen on the ionic view. If I do the same withe the ionic v1 it works.

```
ionic start sample --v2
cd sample
ionic lab
ionic upload
```

It shows white but

```
ionic start sample
cd sample
ionic lab
ionic upload
```

It works perfectly. No changes on the code at all
Thanks

Comment: Ionic 2 needs minimum Android v4.4 or up. See Ionic Documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/#browser-support)

Comment: Remove the --v2 flag as a latest version sample would already be created.

Answer (score 9):

ionic 2 needs at least 4.4 android to work, lost a lot of time on this and there is nothing on the ionic website informing about that. Writing down here to help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Ionic v2 supports android 4.4 and up. The older browser on pre-4.4 devices do not have the features needed for ionic2 and angular 2 to work. Though this can be fixed with [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The supported platforms are list here:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/#browser-support

You can go back to 4.1 with crosswalk it states.

Answer (score 0):

ionic 2 needs at least 4.4 android to work,.. for more info debug app in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

from ionic 2 Ionic officially stops to use ionic lab.
You can run and test your app in browser using command "ionic serve".

Answer (score 0):

Ionic2 app was initially created with --v2 flag but now they removed it . So nothing happens with --v2

Answer (score 0):

Better way to solve the code 1st time by running directly into android devices by

```
Ionic cordova run android or
Ionic run android
```

Then connect your device with your system and open chrome and enter chrome://inspect to the url

Now you can console log the the error and can find the way of solutions.

Now try to run by ionic view

Answer (score 0):

Remove the platform and then add it again.

Answer (score 0):

please try eionic start sample --type=ionic-angular